# I have pressed fn+insert key by mistake and my screen blanked and keyboard and mouse are also not working. How do I get it right?

Tags: suspend, wakeup

I have recently updated to Linux 20.04 Lts but sometimes it suspends and although the power switch stays on, nothing works. I am unable to wake my laptop by pressing any key or with mouse. This time I pressed fn + insert and the screen has gone off and neither keyboard nor mouse works. But if I switch off the laptop and reboot it again everything works fine but all my unsaved work is gone. Please help me to get out of this situation.

Comment: Please try and be specific; Linux strictly refers to a kernel, and lots of systems use 20.04 like Ubuntu does, so details help us to understand. Linux (kernel) allows the use of keyboard commands such as SysRq combinations that allow you to give commands directly to the (linux) kernel so even if a GUI/desktop has died, the kernel can respond to the given command (a far better option than switching power off; not all keyboard brands include SysRq key, some offer alternatives, some require change before hand though). A easy reference can be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: Details would help us to help you better.  Updated from? to?  What system of 20.04? (ie. Ubuntu 20.04 or something else? another flavor?)  how are you suspending? command? gui? do all methods do the same?

Comment: I have been using dell latitude 3490. I was previously using Linux ubuntu 18.04 lts version and then I removed it and installed ubuntu 20.04 lts, gnome version- 3.36.2. I tried suspending by putting my laptop screen down, and by the suspend option in the top bar and also by a suspend app in the menu. Sometimes it works but almost all the time the power button keeps on but nothing works like pressing any key or using my trackpad, the screen kept off and no response from keyboard.